# Strange issue with populating LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, logic, bigdecimal, linkedhashset

Given the below code, is there some reason that when the final if-else statement steps into the else clause, if I un-comment the two lines of code and comment the "FOOZANAZABAR" and "TESTCAIRO" lines, that it would not add those lines into the LinkedHashSet?  It appears to add
    values.add(new BigDecimal(PEUNIT).multiply(new BigDecimal(1000)).toString());
correctly when the logic drops into the else clause, but will not add the BD.ZERO or the PEFAMT to that field DESPITE the fact they are strings.

As a note, the ZERO and PEFAMT are BigDecimal's that are converted to a string.  These are the only two values that are giving me grief.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> convertTransactionTableData(ResultSet rs) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> returnableMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> ();

    try {
        while (rs.next()){
            String PEFAMT, PEPOLN, MCISST, PEBRCD, PEEFFY, PEPLAN;
            String PEUNIT, PETRNC, PECO, PEITYP, ZERO;

            PEPOLN = rs.getString("PEPOLN");
            MCISST = rs.getString("MCISST");
            PEBRCD = rs.getBigDecimal("PEBRCD").toString();
            PEEFFY = rs.getBigDecimal("PEEFFY").toString();
            PEPLAN = rs.getString("PEPLAN");
            PEUNIT = rs.getBigDecimal("PEUNIT").toString();
            PEFAMT = rs.getBigDecimal("PEFAMT").toString();
            PETRNC = rs.getString("PETRNC");
            PECO = rs.getString("PECO");
            PEITYP = DataConverter.resetInsuranceType(rs.getString("PEITYP"));
            ZERO = BigDecimal.ZERO.toPlainString();

            String policyNumber = PEPOLN;
            LinkedHashSet<String> values = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
            values.add(MCISST);
            values.add(PEBRCD);
            values.add(PEEFFY);
            values.add(PEPLAN);
            values.add(PEUNIT);
            if (PEPLAN.equalsIgnoreCase("HSRE")) {
                values.add(new BigDecimal(PEUNIT).multiply(new BigDecimal(1000)).toString());
            } else {
                values.add(PEFAMT);
            }
            values.add(PETRNC);
            values.add(PECO);
            values.add(PEITYP);
            if (DataConverter.testStringToInt(PETRNC)) {
                if (Integer.valueOf(PETRNC) >= 20 && Integer.valueOf(PETRNC) <= 29) {
                    values.add(PEFAMT);
                    values.add(ZERO);
                    values.add(ZERO);
                } else {
                    values.add("FOOZANZABAR");
                    values.add("TESTCAIRO");
//                      values.add(ZERO);
//                      values.add(PEFAMT);
                    values.add(new BigDecimal(PEUNIT).multiply(new BigDecimal(1000)).toString());
                }
            }
            returnableMap.put(policyNumber, values);
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        logger.error("Problem converting the ResultSet.  ", sqlEx);
    }
    return returnableMap;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

- Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the underlying data structure you're using here is a **SET** which means it won't let you add duplicates. In all probability, the ***string values*** of BD.ZERO and PEFAMT must already be present in your `values` set and are hence getting ignored.

If this turns out to be the case simply switch to using `LinkedList<String>` that allows you to have duplicates.